# Error con DRF: el objeto no tiene el atributo modelo

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Estoy tratando de crear una API REST en mi aplicación de [django](/questions/tagged/django) v1.9, con [django-rest-framework](/questions/tagged/django-rest-framework) v3.3.2, pero al ejecutar el servidor me aparece este error:

> AttributeError: 'Politica' object has no attribute 'model'

Este es mi modelo:

```
class Politica(TimeStampedModel):
    revision = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Revisión")
    fecha = models.DateField(
        "Fecha",
        help_text="Fecha de aprobación de la revisión")
    politica = models.TextField(
        "Política",
        help_text="Contenido de la poítica de la calidad")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Política'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Políticas'
        get_latest_by = 'id'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%02d - %s" % (self.revision, self.fecha)
```

> El objetivo de este modelo es llevar un control de un documento llamado *Política de la Calidad*. Cada registro en la base de datos de `Politica` es una versión de este documento y la versión actual o aprobada, es la más reciente, que obtengo con esta consulta: `Politica.objects.latest()`.
>
> Mi objetivo es que la API solo devuelva la política más reciente, que sería, digámoslo así, la **política aprobada**.

En el archivo `serializers.py` tengo lo siguiente:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Politica

class PoliticaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Politica
        fields = ('revision', 'fecha', 'politica')
```

En mi archivo de vistas, tengo lo siguiente:

```
from .models import Politica
from .serializers import PoliticaSerializer

class PoliticaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PoliticaSerializer
    model = Politica
    queryset = Politica.objects.latest()
```

> Esta última línea es la que me causa el error que describo más abajo. Línea esperada es `Politica.objects.all()`. Cualquier intento de obtener un solo registro provoca el mismo error.
>
> De este modo, no puedo usar `last()`, ni `Politica.objects.all()[1]` o cualquier opción similar.

En mi archivo `urls.py` defino, entre otras cosas, lo siguiente:

```
from django.conf.urls import include #, url, patterns

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'politica', PoliticaViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls))
]
```

Tal como está `PoliticaViewSet` me sale este error:

```
(cmi) toledano@toledano src (feature/politica) $ python manage.py runserver --settings=core.settings.local
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10d5cd7b8>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ### Líneas removidas para mayor legibilidad
  File "/Volumes/datos/proyectos/cmi/src/core/urls.py", line 15, in <module>
    router.register(r'politica', PoliticaViewSet)
  File "/Users/toledano/.entornos/cmi/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 60, in register
    base_name = self.get_default_base_name(viewset)
  File "/Users/toledano/.entornos/cmi/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 139, in get_default_base_name
    return queryset.model._meta.object_name.lower()
AttributeError: 'Politica' object has no attribute 'model'
```

Para poder eliminar el error, tengo que cambiar en el archivo `serialzers.py` mi *queryset* por uno que devuelva todos los registros de la tabla.

Mi objetivo es obtener solo un registro, *el más reciente*. **¿Qué debería cambiar para obtener solo el registro buscado?**.

Agradeceré cualquier respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de investigar un rato, el problema es que estoy usando de forma incorrecta el `ViewSet`.

### El serializador

Para convertir los datos en objetos objetos `JSON`, estoy usando un `ModelSerializer` que de forma automática:

- genera el conjunto de campos que tiene el modelo
- crea los validadores de los campos o del modelo, como `unique_together`
- incluye las implementaciones para `.create()` y `.update()`

Debo pasar por este serializador, un objeto de tipo `Politica`, ya sea un queryset o un registro individual.

### El ViewSet

La clase `ViewSet` genera dos clases de respuestas, una **lista** y un **detalle**, que se pasan por el serializador para obtener los datos en `JSON` y es aquí donde tengo el problema.

En el ejemplo de `Politica`, la lista es un *queryset* que contiene todas las versiones de la política de la calidad, y el detalle devuelve una y solo una política, que por default se obtiene del identificador `pk`.

Y este es mi problema: pretendo regresar un registro único en una lista. El error que se reporta ese, que espera un queryset y estoy mandando un objeto simple.

Si quiero un solo objeto en la lista no puedo usar `queryset = Politica.objects.latest()` que devuelve un objeto individual. En su lugar, debería usar `queryset = Politica.objects.latest()[:1]` que convierte el resultado en una lista con un único valor.

### Conclusión

Un **ViewSet** es excelente para crear una API de un modelo de sin ningún esfuerzo.

> Ahora que ya comprendí mi error, debo plantear otro problema.